# Isn't using Atomic-object and synchronized together redundant?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am reviewing and refactoring, if possible, my collegue's old code. And I found this class that uses `AtomicInteger` as a field variable, and it also has `sychronized(this)` to update the value of the variable.

The code looks like below

```java
public class FooPool{
    ...
    private final AtomicInteger poolCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    ...
    
    private void incrementPoolCount(){
        synchronized (this) {
            if(!poolCount.get() >= maxSize) {
                poolCount.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems redundant to me that using a `synchronized` keyword to call the methods that `Atomic-` classes provide because, as far as I understand, those methods are already thread-safe methods.

Please tell me if I miss something or is there any case that you use those two expressions together to secure thread-safety.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. The `synchronized` does more than just "call the methods", it ensures that the comparison and increment happen simultaneously. That said, it looks like an attempt to reimplement a `Semaphore`.

Comment: You are using a custom check-then-act compound action, so you need to make it atomic. So a synchronised is indeed needed here.

Answer (score 0):

The code executed under lock first checks a condition, then changes the value on which the condition depends.

If the two actions were not atomic, two threads could read `poolCount` simultaneously when it is equal to `maxSize` minus one, and therefore increment it twice, above `maxSize`.

So, the lock is needed.

If `poolCount` is not used elsewhere, or is used only with the same lock held, or is only read, it can be replaced with an `int` variable, `volatile` depending on the case.